# Android Copy and Paste with TextView

Tags: android, clipboard

I have a textview which displays a lot of text.

My users want to highlight and copy a snip of code to the clipboard.

Any pointers on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Copy Paste - Android Developers Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html)?

Answer (score 5):

Modify the `textIsSelectable` property:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```