# How do I enable standard copy paste for a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, copy-paste

I want to enable standard copy paste for a TextView (the same as for EditText). How can I do it?

I tried using a non-editable EditText but it didn't work well (sometimes it became editable or the copy paste overlay was not shown). And it's probably not a good approach generally.

Need a working solution starting at API 7.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605155/android-copy-and-paste-with-textview) what you are looking for?

Comment: It's similar, but not the same because I want to copy all the text. But it looks the same. The problem is that the answer there only works starting at API 11 and I need something which works from API 7.

Comment: `ClipboardManager` is available since API 1 (look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) ). How about long press, with a popup to copy to clipboard?

Comment: @Jermin Yes, it seems I have to make a custom solution.

Comment: The new way to do it in 2023 is explained in [this document](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/copy-paste)
It relies on the new `android.content.ClipboardManager` API

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This works for copy pre-Honeycomb:

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager;

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.setText(textView.getText());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: A good strategy would be to use this along with CommonsWare's answer. Since adding `android:textIsSelectable` lives in the layout, it will just get ignored on lower API levels. Then use Ixx's solution within an if statement that checks to see if the API level is below 11. Best of both worlds. The nice thing about `android:textIsSelectable` is that it gives you the platform's text selection action bar, and has a nice native feeling.

Comment: The method setText(CharSequence) from the type ClipboardManager is deprecated

Comment: Yes, well, this answer is from more than 2 years ago. Feel free to edit or add a new one.

Answer (score 288):

Try [`android:textIsSelectable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textIsSelectable).

i.e., `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: Can one do it for EditTextPreference?

Comment: @powder366: I would think that `EditTextPreference` already supports copy/paste. It certainly seems to in the Settings app.

Comment: Actually it seems to be a bug. Shows up on my Samsung 4.2.2 device. Nexus7 and Nexus10 works. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26008

Comment: Just a note on this, if your text view is initially hidden and you are showing it programatically using setVisibility, then you need to use textView.setTextIsSelectable(true) to make this work. It won't work via xml in that case.

Answer (score 67):

To enable the standard copy/paste for TextView, U can choose one of the following:

1. Change in layout file: add below property to your TextView

   `android:textIsSelectable="true"`
2. In your Java class write this line to set it programmatically. `myTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);`

And long press on the TextView you can see copy/paste action bar.

Comment: i do so. as i click on texts the toolbar with "copy" and "select al"l buttons open. but after i click them nothing happen. what can i do?

Comment: This solution is better than the one marked correct with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 16):

In xml textview paste this code

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Then in java file,

```
 final TextView txtcopypaste = findViewById(R.id.txtcopypaste); // my textview
    txtcopypaste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // set onclick listener to my textview
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(txtcopypaste.getText().toString());              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Requirement :** Need to copy and paste the text which is in the textview.

**OutCome :** Using textview , once i clicked the textview. Its automatically copied the text  which is in the textview.

**Note:** While importing clipboardmanager try to prefer

Please prefer text clipboard manager

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager; // prefer this
```

try to avoid content clipboard manager

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager; // Not this
```

Answer (score 12):

> [Requires API 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html), Updated Code, previous method is deprecated

**Solution for theme full screen without** `ActionBar`

Extend `TextView` and in constructor paste following code

```
this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager cManager = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData cData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", getText());
                cManager.setPrimaryClip(cData);
                Util.toast(mContext, string.text_copyed);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

1. use theme

   ```
   @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
   ```

   or

   ```
   @android:style/Theme.WithActionBar
   ```
2. set TextView in xml

   ```
   android:textIsSelectable="true"
   ```
3. see [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9JD.png)

Answer (score 2):

if someone wants to go the extra mile and do the select and copy to the clipboard with one click :

```
 phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("PhoneNumber", phone.getText());
                            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                        }
                    });
```

phone is the `TextView` and `phone.Text` is the Text that will be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can enable the **Standard Copy/Paste**:

`TextView` class has a definition:

```
boolean canPaste() {
    return (mText instanceof Editable
            && mEditor != null && mEditor.mKeyListener != null
            && getSelectionStart() >= 0
            && getSelectionEnd() >= 0
            && getClipboardManagerForUser().hasPrimaryClip());
}
```

Which can be bypassed using:

```
public static void enableCopyPaste(final TextView tv) {
    if(tv.getKeyListener()==null){
        tv.setKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

                @Override
                public void clearMetaKeyState(View p1, Editable p2, int p3) {
                    // unused
                }

                @Override
                public int getInputType() {
                    return tv.getInputType();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onKeyDown(View p1, Editable p2, int p3, KeyEvent p4) {
                    // unused
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onKeyOther(View p1, Editable p2, KeyEvent p3) {
                    // unused
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onKeyUp(View p1, Editable p2, int p3, KeyEvent p4) {
                    // unused
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    tv.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    CharSequence mText = tv.getText();
    if(!(mText instanceof Editable)){
        tv.setText(mText,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

By calling:

```
enableCopyPaste(YOUR_TEXTVIEW);
```

***Ps: It also enables Cut, Share etc***

Answer (score -1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189589/4665578) is better:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
final android.content.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
final android.content.ClipData clipData = android.content.ClipData
        .newPlainText("text label", "text to clip");
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
} else {
final android.text.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboardManager.setText("text to clip");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you have to set `FullScreen` theme on your `activity` or `fragment` first of all!

@

```
Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

and in `layout.xml` in `textview` add:

```
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Done!

Answer (score -2):

For an `EditText`,
in manifest inside the activity use 
 `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`