# How to Enable Default Copy paste on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I define Edittext inside xml layout but when i select text inside EditText default cut copy paste not appeare.

**here my xml code**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xEt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

**my java code is:**

```
    mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xEt);
    mEt.setTypeface(tf2);
    mEt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    mEt.setTextSize(30);
```

[image]

Comment: call setTextIsSelectable(true)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android

Comment: Did you try this ??? ^^ let me inform

Comment: yes but still not work. i define in xml `android:textIsSelectable="true"` as well as java.

Comment: also set setfocusableintouchmode(true).

Comment: what api level are you working on ?

Comment: i use api level 11, actually copy icon color is white, but now paste is not working... and how to changes its color

Comment: i am using AutoCompeteTextView and i have set setTextIsSelectable(true) but still it's not working

Comment: change themes it should be work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable standard copy paste for a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

`Set android:textIsSelectable="true"` (API Level 11 and above) then look into the Clipboard manager in  : [Copy and Paste](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

Comment: i try **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13004720/2387564)** for copy paste but how to use clipboard manger it crash my app. using this **[tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm)**