# Enable copy-paste for edittext in PopupWindow in android

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

I'm using PopupWindow to get some data from users. Surprisingly, I'm unable to select text inside the EditText layout which is the requirement, as I want user to be able to copy(from anywhere) and paste here. I've explicitly used **`android:textIsSelectable="true"`** for my EditText. Here are the attributes I'm using for EditText.

```
       <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/actionable_horizontal_margin"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Email"
        />
```

I'm also setting **`popup.setFocusable(true)`**. Is there something else that needs to be done?

My copy paste is working fine for other EditTexts in activities and fragments.

P.S. I don't want to use custom Clipboard actions.

Comment: please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710490/how-to-enable-default-copy-paste-on-edittext

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Still no solution for that? I can barely imagine that Android is unable to do that without major modification or an own implementation of a copy/paste menu.