# How can I make the copy menu appear in a TextView upon the initial selection of text?

Tags: android, textview, copy-paste

Similar questions, such as [How do I enable standard copy paste for a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android), have appeared on StackOverflow in the past and the standard answer is to add the `android:textIsSelectable` property to your TextView. This allows the text to be selected after short or long pressing but the copy menu does not immediately appear. Instead, you need to lift your finger and then long press a second time on the selected text in order for this menu to appear.

Is it possible to make it so that the copy menu appears after the initial text selection instead of after the second long press?