# How to select and copy text by pressing long in textView?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm working in Android Studio 3.0.1. I created a EditText in which I write a text now I want when user long press that text it get copied in clipboard.

I used a method here (which is not working)

`ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mEditText.setText(mClipboard.getText());`

It says *Method Invocation 'get text' may produce 'java.lang.NullpoinyerException'* I need help what should i do ?

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922085/5846135

Comment: no it doesn't solve my problem, i want a method through which i can copy text in clipboard

Comment: Are you want to copy full edittext text ? @PrateekAwasthi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this , its will work for you :

```
 private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
 private ClipData myClip;

 //inside oncreate
 myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);



 mEditText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
           String text;
            text = mEditText.getText().toString();

            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Abhishek i copied ur code and paste it their but without getting any error my app starts crashing.

Comment: Please check your log what exception are you getting ? @PrateekAwasthi

Comment: every thing looks fine here i even clean my project and gradle build was successful but when i open my app it crashed

Comment: it doesnot resolve OnLongClickListener but it resolves View OnLongClickListener    is this thing crashing my app ? if so how can i solve it ?

Comment: In Android Studio, Click on logcat at bottom and when you will run your app check on logcat , what are you geeting issue ? & tell me @PrateekAwasthi

Comment: it says "FATAL EXCEPTION: main Unable to start activity  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View$OnLongClickListener)' on a null object reference"

Comment: Its saying , Its getting null value when you  long press on edittext. Have to typed any character before long press @PrateekAwasthi

Comment: check ur fb msg. i send to 2 pics there plz. check errors. and give me permanent solution of this

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your help your solution works for me.