# How to select a particular TextView in Android by clicking it and set its text through button

Tags: android

I am developing an Sudoku solver app in Android. I have done designing in Table Layout and each cell has one `TextView`.

How to select a particular `TextView` by clicking it and set its text through button click?

I want like, on `Button` click which ever `TextView` is selected should change it't Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep one variable with `currentSelectedNumber`. On each `TextView`.`onTouchListener` update this variable value

And While clicking button, based on value of this variable update that TextView.

**Sample Code:**

```
int currentSelectedNumber = 0;
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    currentSelectedNumber = 1;                        
                    return true;
                    }
                });
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    currentSelectedNumber = 2;                        
                    return true;
                    }
                });
```

On Button Click:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (currentSelectedNumber){
                            case 0:{
                                tv1.setText("Your Text");
                                break;
                            }
                            case 1:{
                                tv2.setText("Your Text");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you please tell how..I am stuck on it for a long tym

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to copy the text when you long press on your `textview` :

Reference : [How do I enable standard copy paste for a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android)

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager cManager = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData cData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", getText());
            cManager.setPrimaryClip(cData);
            Util.toast(mContext, string.text_copyed);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually I am not asking about copying text.I want to select a TextView by clicking it as I have 9*9 text views present and then write to it a value by clicking buttons from 1 to 9